# Cambiar href de varios etiquetas a con document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Requiero cambiar el href con JavaScript (sin Jquery) en el siguiente código:

```
<div class="set">
    <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4972t07">link a</a>
</div>
<div class="set">
    <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4s972t07">link b</a>
</div>
<div class="set">
    <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4s9720t7d">link c</a>
</div>
```

Requiero cambiarlo por la siguiente URL: `https://www.instagram.com/leonard_avi/`, cuando cargue todo el documento (automáticamente sin darle click)

Comment: ¿Solo desea cambiar a los enlaces que estén dentro de un `div`  con la clase `set` ? o cuál es el criterio ?

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código que has hecho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

### Reemplazo general

Aquí: `document.querySelectorAll('div.set > a')` se seleccionan los anchortags del div cuya clase se llama set.

Luego los recorres en un bucle y haces el cambio.

```js
function cambiarLinks() {
  var nuevoLink = 'https://www.instagram.com/leonard_avi/';
  var eSet = document.querySelectorAll('div.set > a');
  var i = eSet.length;

  while (i--) {
    eSet[i].href = nuevoLink;
    console.log('Cambiado a : '+nuevoLink);
  }
}
window.onload = cambiarLinks;
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4972t07">link a</a>
</div>
<div class="set">
  <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4s972t07">link b</a>
</div>
<div class="set">
  <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4s9720t7d">link c</a>
</div>
```

---

### Reemplazo parcial

En este ejemplo, se conserva el último elemento del enlace. Sería útil en casos en los que se quiera cambiar todo, guardando lo que hace la diferencia al final del enlace.

```js
function cambiarLinks() {
  var nuevoLink = 'https://www.instagram.com/leonard_avi/';
  var eSet = document.querySelectorAll('div.set > a');
  var i = eSet.length;

  while (i--) {
    var viejoLink=eSet[i].href;
    var viejoUltimo=viejoLink.substr(viejoLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var nuevoFinal=nuevoLink+viejoUltimo;
    eSet[i].href = nuevoFinal;
    console.log('Cambiado a : '+nuevoFinal);
  }
}
window.onload = cambiarLinks;
```

```html
<div class="set">
  <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4972t07">link a</a>
</div>
<div class="set">
  <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4s972t07">link b</a>
</div>
<div class="set">
  <a href="https://snapwidget.com/embed/4s9720t7d">link c</a>
</div>
```